Automatically quiet my devices to a "silent mode" based on time and location? (1 x Win11 + 2 x Android)
I have set up a situation here where I have installed Whatsapp v2.24.19.82 (of the same number on my phone, tablet and laptop), I have also set up Phone Link between my laptop and phone. So, whenever I get a call it's a monstrous cacophony of multiple ringtones. It's very noticable and glaring.
The Phone Link is the most annoying as it still tones a few seconds more after picking up the call.
I have to attend lectures sparsely throughout the day and the reason I'm posting this situation now is because I was in a silent study space and the devices went off like mad.
Is it possible (it must be) to detect time, location or calendar event inorder to mute/silence the devices. I cannot go through the process of quieting them and unquieting them every single day and inbetween every single class.
Please provide me with a solution on what to do inorder to resolve my situation. Surely, I am not the only one who has faced this situation and likely not the last person to face it either.
References:

Whatsapp 
1.1) https://about.meta.com/technologies/whatsapp/
1.2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp
1.3) https://web.whatsapp.com/
1.4) https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nksqgp7f2nh?hl=en-US&gl=US
PhoneLink 
2.1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7K-erl2xhjY&t=2s
2.2) https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/sync-across-your-devices
2.3) https://pair.phonelink.microsoft.com/

Device Descriptions:

(Phone) Samsung Galaxy A15 SM-A156E/DS - Android 14 One UI 6.1
(Tab) Samsung Galaxy Tab A9+ 5G SM-X216B - Android 14 One UI 6.1
(Laptop) Lenovo Legion Onyx Quest 83DV (LOQ 15IRX9) - Windows 11 64-bit Monolingual

Your effort in solving this is much appreciated.
